# How to serialize scala BKTree?

Tags: scala, serialization

I am note sure whether i should ask this question here. I have a scala class that extends serializable but when i try saving the class using fileoutputstream,i keep getting NotSerializableException.

```
class BKTree(terms: Seq[String], dist: (String, String) => Int = Levenshtein.distance) extends scala.serializable{

}

class BKNode(val name: String,dist: (String, String) => Int = Levenshtein.distance) extends scala.serializable{

}

object Levenshtein extends scala.serializable {

}
```

The BKTree generated works perfectely fine,but on trying to save the tree it generates NotSerializableException.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should extend `Serializable` (or `java.io.Serializable`). `serializable` is a deprecated annotation.
2. You can't serialize arbitrary functions (like `dist`).

One workaround I can suggest:

```
// require that distance functions be serializable
trait DistFunction extends (String, String) => Int with Serializable

object Levenshtein {
  val distance: DistFunction = ...
}

class BKTree(terms: Seq[String], dist: DistFunction) extends Serializable

...
```

Note that you'll have to ensure your `distance` implementation actually *is* serializable.

Comment: I have already done that. Both the classes extends Serializable.

Comment: Then you should look at `Levenshtein.distance` implementation (or whatever function the tree uses for `dist`). It probably refers to some non-serializable object. See http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/spores.html#serialization

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understand,but is there any other way to serialize such classes in scala? because i have tried different Serializable libs too.The results are similar.

Comment: You have to either make your function serializable or avoid making it part of your data structure.